# VS Code automatically restart debugger on file save like nodemon

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to automatically restart the node debugger in VS Code when a source file changes like nodemon?

Comment: You can just use nodemon :) The debugger will work with it.

Comment: Unfortunately NO.

Answer (score 10):

You can use nodemon even for debugging. Below are the steps to configure in VS Code

1. Open VSCode
2. On top toolbar, go to Run > Add Configuration
3. `launch.json` file will be created. Open that file and change as below

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\**app.js**",
            **"restart": true,
            "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon"**
        }
    ]
```

Make sure nodemon is installed globally. Also your entry point to server is `app.js`, if its different change it to that file name.

Comment: Life saviour. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot automatically restart the node debugger when the source file changes, but you could use a separate debugger that does monitor source file changes such as node-inspector.

[node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) developed by StrongLoop also has a feature that allows you to edit your source code within the debugger while the server is running.

Install node-inspector

```
$ npm install -g node-inspector
```

Start the node-inspector server

```
$ node-inspector
```

Enable debug mode in your node process

```
$ node --debug your/node/program.js
```

Load the debugger UI

Open http://127.0.0.1:8080/?port=5858 in the Chrome browser